# How to add child application using Microsoft.Web.Administration?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-10

I am using .NET Core Console application to create web site and its child application like below

```
        ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
        Site webSite = serverManager.Sites.Add("MywebSite", @"C:\MywebSite", 80);            
        webSite.Applications.Add("Child1","C:\MyChildApplication");
        webSite.ServerAutoStart = true;
        serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

However i am getting error

> System.Exception: Invalid application path
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostProperty.set_Value(Object
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.SetAttributeValue(String
>   attributeName, Object value)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationCollection.Add(String path,
>   String physicalPath)    at
>   IISHelper.CreateWebSites(Settings
>   settings) in XXXXXXXXX\IISHelper.cs:line
>   14    at
>   XXXX.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   XXXXXXXXX\Program.cs:line 15

Comment: Try `/Child1` instead.

Comment: That worked !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All applications need to have their paths starting with `/` (a convention with little explanation, so simply follow it).

Thus, in your case, you should use `/Child1`.